# Pegar imagem da galeria e salvar em uma determinada pasta

Tags: android, imagem

Como eu faço pra pegar uma imagem da galeria(utilizando o ImageView) e salvá-lá em uma pasta que eu criei em me SDcard?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza o gestor de ficheiros, procura a pasta onde ficam guardadas as fotos no tlm e depois é só cortar (ou copiar) e colar no destino, se quer isso de forma permanete entra nas configurações da camera e tem uma opeção para trocar o armazenamento das fotos e muda para o cartao.

Comment: Eu preciso disso a nível de programação.